How can I print the image field with printJs in Angular?
I've an Angular app and using print.JS in somewhere in my app .I have a method that takes the dynamic information from the database and as table prints it with the print.js component, I also have an image field in the columns that I convert to Base64 first, but it doesn't print.

please share the minimal reproducible code

To print an image field in Angular using Print.js, you need to pass the image source (URL or data URI) to Print.js. Print.js can directly print images by specifying the type: 'image' option. 

Step 1: Install Print.js (npm install print-js)
Step 2: Import Print.js in Your Component (import printJS from 'print-js';)
Step 3: Use Print.js to Print the Image

printImage() {
  printJS({
    printable: 'https://example.com/path/to/image.jpg', // URL of the image
    type: 'image',
    style: 'img { max-width: 100%; height: auto; }' // Optional styling
  });
}

Step 4: Trigger Print Function in HTML

<button (click)="printImage()">Print Image</button>

